# Django Create Foreign key to external table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django app which works with a subset of tables within a database. What I want is to create a foreign key to a table which is not managed by the django app, reason is that I want to cascade on delete.

Is it possible to declare a foreign key in my django model to a table which is not controled by my django app?

Something like:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(table='external_table_name',field='user_id',
                         on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#managed) options for your model to:

`managed=False`

Comment: thanks, missed that.. this in conjunction with db_table = 'table_name' did the trick